# Display the processes whose PID is less than a predetermined number

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

I have a text file in a subdirectory of the current directory with the name `P_R.txt` which contains a list of processes (output of the command `ps -aux`). The file looks like this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  3.0  0.3 137476  7428 ?        Ss   16:13   0:05 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:13   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:13   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:13   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
```

I need to display processes which have a PID smaller then some number R

Comment: PID can not be only 4 digital number as far as i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `subdir` with the name of your subdirectory and `R` with your number...

```
awk '{if ($2 < R) print $0}' subdir/P_R.txt
```

- `if ($2 < R)` if the number in the second column is less than R...
- `print $0` print the whole line

If you just want the process names then just print that column:

```
awk '{if ($2 < R) print $11}' subdir/P_R.txt
```

Comment: @advardo it's a pleasure :)

Comment: Does awk ignore the first header row (`USER PID` etc)?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju yes it does ignore it